# IOE error using dataframe.to_csv and dataframe.save to write data to files

Tags: python, pandas, ioerror

I was trying to save dataframe for later use in pandas.
However, I had the error below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/source/Linux/pkg/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/series.py", line 2881, in to_csv
    encoding=encoding)
  File "/source/Linux/pkg/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1393, in to_csv
    formatter.save()
  File "/source/Linux/pkg/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/format.py", line 963, in save
    f.close()
IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

`dataframe.save` fails even for a simple object `a = DataFrame({'a':[1,3,4],'b':[3,4,5]})`.

Comment: Show some sample data and input, particularly the line of code that throws the error

Answer (score 0):

The `save` method is deprecated. You should us `to_pickle` instead. It looks like you're using pandas 0.11 which quite old. The latest version is 0.16. 
You could also consider saving it to csv or HDF5. 
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html

Comment: Thanks so much. Actually I work on a remote server and I have no right to install items. The to_csv method caused  the same error. Maybe I need talk to the administrator.

Comment: Finally I found that this error is caused by the storage limit. There is only 2Gb quota available for me on that remote server. Don't know what to say. Sign

Comment: Sometimes the error messages from pandas aren't very descriptive or helpful. Glad you got to the bottom of it